# "Remove unused references" missing in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I'm wondering why my Visual Studio missing "Remove unused references" on right click menu project and references both.[image: missing menu item]

Please Don't tell me try Migrate packages.config to PackageReference, I just did it, but nothing change.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/54801

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to have an SDK style csproj like it is said [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/54801).

Example:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk"/>
```

Second, you must have it enabled like @Stan1k mentioned in his answer:

> Microsoft says that the feature is off by default. You need to enable it from Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced tab > Show "Remove Unused References" command in Solution Explorer (experimental).

And finally make sure you you run `dotnet restore` in the project console and build the projects (this was the issue for my why it was not showing).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an older Visual Studio Version? This Feature got released with [**Version 16.10**](https://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2021/03/remove-unused-reference-feature-in-visual-studio-2019.html).
Also notice this statement from the article

> Microsoft says that the feature is off by default. You need to enable it from Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced tab.

Comment: Version 16.11.3 and it's enabled, but I don't see it anywhere

Comment: Okay that's pretty weird.. Of course you could try to reinstall the IDE but I'm not sure if it would solve the problem. Did you tried to use it on other projects?

Answer (score -1):

The option appears in Options>C#>Advanced and is on. When you right click on project the option does not appear making me think all references are being used. Perhaps depends on the project.

Answer (score -1):

This utility was available for VB projects up until around VS2015 I think, maybe VS2013, then it got removed or limited for some reason. I've never seen it available in C# projects. And now it's not even available for VB unless your have an SDK project type. It's a bit ridiculous because often downgrading a NuGet package (eg RestSharp) will leave a load of "reference rubble" which you have to (carefully) clean up.

As an aside, whenever I install a new version of VS, it seems that much of their effort goes into UI look and feel rather than actual functionality improvements. Quite frustrating.